# Should a Rails app load its .env file when its tests run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Should my app be calling `Dotenv.load` when its running its test suite?

Without calling `Dotenv.load` while running my test suite, rspec fails with an error about missing an environment key. I have pasted the error and its stack trace below.

```
$ rspec

An error occurred while loading ./spec/requests/users/create_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

KeyError:
  key not found: "REDIS_URL"
# (erb):11:in `fetch'
# (erb):11:in `<main>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:233:in `config_for'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:85:in `<module:Server>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:4:in `<module:ActionCable>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable.rb:44:in `server'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `eval_block'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:443:in `block in clear!'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:443:in `each'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:443:in `clear!'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `block in clear!'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:48:in `each'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:48:in `clear!'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:17:in `reload!'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
# /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/users/create_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/requests/users/create_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: When your test suite misses a key that is set by a `.env` or `.env.test` file then your application should probably load the environment config. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a Rails app you want to do the following:

```
require 'dotenv/tasks'

task start: [:dotenv] do
  # this Rake tasks depends on the dotenv  loading task
  puts 'hi'
end
```

Inside a Rails app:

Since you're actually *in* a Rails app, I would make sure you're using `dotenv-rails` in your Gemfile, instead of just `dotenv`. The former will auto run the dotenv stuff as part of the Rails startup routine